# Writing CSV through Python Lists leads to blank rows between the data

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I have an example of writing a csv from python:

```
import csv

# field names 
fields = ['Name', 'Branch', 'Year', 'CGPA'] 

# data rows of csv file 
rows = [ ['Nikhil', 'COE', '2', '9.0'], 
     ['Sanchit', 'COE', '2', '9.1'], 
     ['Aditya', 'IT', '2', '9.3'], 
     ['Sagar', 'SE', '1', '9.5'], 
     ['Prateek', 'MCE', '3', '7.8'], 
     ['Sahil', 'EP', '2', '9.1']] 

 with open('Test.csv', 'w') as f:
 
# using csv.writer method from CSV package
 
 write = csv.writer(f)
 write.writerow(fields)
 write.writerows(rows)
```

this works fine, except i have the following result:

```
Name,Branch,Year,CGPA

Nikhil,COE,2,9.0

Sanchit,COE,2,9.1

Aditya,IT,2,9.3

Sagar,SE,1,9.5

Prateek,MCE,3,7.8

Sahil,EP,2,9.1
```

As you can see in my csv i have blanks between the data. I dont understand where these breaks come from, any idea?

Comment: Please show the actual code you're running. What you show here is syntactically flawed

Comment: What is in the upper box i am running in my notebook, please further explain what code is missing, i will provide it

Comment: You cannot possibly run that code. The first argument to *open()* is not valid. Your attempts to write to the file are not indented under *with*

Comment: yep, there is a `'` missing before `Test.csv` and the following lines of code need to be indented

Comment: ok i cut out my path string for data security purposes. i see its technically not correct atm

Comment: @MrIrrelevant Did you cut out the indentation too? Please review: [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: yeah i cutted the indentation by accident

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `newline = ''` in your writer part:

```
import csv

fields = ['Name', 'Branch', 'Year', 'CGPA']
rows = [['Nikhil', 'COE', '2', '9.0'],
        ['Sanchit', 'COE', '2', '9.1'],
        ['Aditya', 'IT', '2', '9.3'],
        ['Sagar', 'SE', '1', '9.5'],
        ['Prateek', 'MCE', '3', '7.8'],
        ['Sahil', 'EP', '2', '9.1']]

with open('Test.csv', 'w', newline = '') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(fields)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```